# Generate outer(1:10,1:10) matrix in R using for() do() loop statement

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I am looking to make a simple code in R to generate a matrix like the one below..

I know you start one like:

```
 for(i in 1:10){
```

But I am not sure where to go from here. I know I can just  use `outer(1:10,1:10)` but am looking to use a `for()` `do()` statement.

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
 1  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  
 2  2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20  
 3  3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30  
 4  4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  
 5  5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  
 6  6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  
 7  7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  
 8  8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  
 9  9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90 
 10 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100
```

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this with `for`?

Comment: Is there another easy way to do it? I have no idea..

Comment: In general, `for` loops are quite inefficient in R; it is often better to do everything using vector logic. You already know how to do this with `outer`. So I assume that you have a more complex problem than this one, one you cannot solve with `outer`. I just wonder whether a `for` loop will be the best way to do it.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Honestly, `for` loops aren't so bad if you don't grow an object. They do get pretty awful for large numbers of iterations due to the function call overhead, but otherwise don't deserve the stigma they've attracted.

Comment: @sebastian-c: you can reduce the function call overhead by putting the loop in a function and compiling it. Also, in addition to growing objects, using data.frames in a loop is slow, but that's because data.frames are slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me to explain `outer`, you need 2 loops ( at least how I would do if I want to implement it)

```
v <- c()
for(i in 1:10)
  for(j in 1:10)
    v <- c(v,i*j)      ## This is SLOW! (naughty)
matrix(v,ncol=10,nrow=10)
```

**EDIT**

In my last implementation I allocate dynamically the size of the matrix which is very slow. It is better to allocate the matrix before the loops, something like this:

```
xx <- matrix(NA,ncol=10,nrow=10)
for(i in 1:10)
  for(j in 1:10)
    xx[i,j] <- i*j
```

Another way to do with vectors:

```
I <- 1:10
J <- 1:10
I %*% t(J)
```

Comment: You should know better than to grow an object inside a loop... naughty.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich tyanks !I update my answer. My purpose was to show that `outer` is mathematically based in 2 indexs.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is a kinda silly thing to do as `outer` is a way better option. For fun and educational purposes:

```
#Define dimensions
matx <- 10
maty <- 10
mat <- matrix(NA, matx, maty)

#For loop
for(i in seq_len(maty)){
  mat[,i] <- i * seq_len(matx)
}
```

Note that I've defined the size of the matrix before looping. This will prevent the horrors of growing an object as described in the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion:

```
lines = 10
output= seq(from=1,by=1,length.out=columns)
i=2
while (i<lines+1){
  temp2 = seq(from=i, by=i, length.out=lines)
  output= cbind(output, temp2)
  i = i+1
}
```